# How to check for a value in multiple columns in R ( finding array equivalent in SAS)?

Tags: r, arrays, loops, sas

I have a large dataframe where I want to check for a value "Y" , if present in multiple columns.
If so, then I will have to create a new character column and assign value 1 there otherwise, need to assign blank where the condition doesn't match.

NB: the columns are not next to each other neither they carry any common string in their names.
As a SAS professional I'm familiarized with arrays to solve this and as a beginner in R, would really like to explore the methods to approach this problem. Though I've figured a way that creating a function by using For loop might solve, would really appreciate if one can guide in that direction please. Thanks!!
[image]

There are other columns purposefully dropped, need help to write a code irrespective of position. As the column names will remain same, but position may(more dynamic). By using For loop is what I'm looking forward to create so that it run over some specific column names or may be even the entire DF and if any column contain value "Y", then it will create a new column and flag it as value 1, else it will be contain blank.

Comment: I think the help you've received so far is about all you can get given no sample data and no help on column-selection (to test for the presence of `"Y"`). At the top of the [tag:r] tag, it suggests providing data with the use of `dput(.)`, likely on a subset of the data (just enough to prove the point).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Ronak, added the example of dataset as guided.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
df1$newcol <-  +(rowSums(df1 == 'Y', na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

---

If we have a set of columns, say from 2nd to 10th

```
df1$newcol <- +(rowSums(df1[2:10] == 'Y', na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

and if the column index are not in the same range, use `c`

```
df1$newcol <- +(rowSums(df1[c(2, 5:10, 25, 39:45)] == 'Y', na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

Comment: Hi Arun, actually the dataframe is huge and the value "Y" is what I'm looking in some specific columns. So is there a way by which explicitely I can mention specific column names and then probably through any function or may be by loop I can run over them to check for "Y". Please guide, if possible

Comment: @sitaram this doesn't require any external packages.

Comment: @sitaram Also, it is very fast and efficient

Comment: Hi @Arun, any specific reason behind usage of "+" before rowsum(), would be helpful if you can guide me know the advantage of using + instead of using ifelse()?, thanks

Comment: @sitaram It coeces `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.  if it works, please consider to upvote/accept. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**An option with dplyr and purrr:**

```
df1%>%mutate(new_col=map(., ~.=='Y')%>%reduce(., `|`)%>%replace(., .==FALSE, NA))
```

You can also select (using both names and positions) in which columns to apply the `== "Y"`comparator with dplyrs `select()`:

```
df1%>%mutate(new_col=select(., c('col_x', 'col_y', 10:20))%>% map(., ~.=='Y')%>%reduce(., `|`)%>%replace(., .==FALSE, NA))
```

An example of this approach with dplyrs built-in starwars dataset:

```
output<-starwars%>%
    mutate(new_col=select(., c('mass', 'skin_color', 6:8))%>%
        map(., ~.=='brown')%>%
        reduce(., `|`)%>%
        replace(., .==FALSE, NA))

output%>%
select(c('mass', 'skin_color', 6:8, new_col))%>%
head()

# A tibble: 6 x 6
   mass skin_color  eye_color birth_year sex    new_col
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>  
1    77 fair        blue            19   male   NA     
2    75 gold        yellow         112   none   NA     
3    32 white, blue red             33   none   NA     
4   136 white       yellow          41.9 male   NA     
5    49 light       brown           19   female TRUE   
6   120 light       blue            52   male   NA
```

Comment: hey @GuedesBF,  Please can you help me know the meaning behind ~. and  reduce(., `|`) portion in your code?

Comment: '~' is short for a lambda function, from the purrr package, which is very useful. It makes writing anonymous functions easier on the eyes. With the lambda, a function which would otherwise be written as `function(x) {x*y}`can be simplified as `~.*y`. The dot `.` is a placeholder for the data that comes from the pipe. For instance, `function_z(data)` can be substituted with `data%>%function_z(.)`

Comment: reduce() also comes from the purrr package. It applies a function recursively over a set of variables. `reduce(c(a , b, c, d), function(x, y)` will do the following: `function(a,b)%>%function(., c)%>% function(., d)`.

Comment: "|" is the OR operator. It can be called as a function

Comment: I also found these concepts difficult to grasp at first, but once you get comfortable with using purrr, you will see it makes EVERYTHING much easier and more consistent.
You should check these excellent resources:

https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html \
https://purrr.tidyverse.org/index.html

Comment: You definitely must use `select()` for convenient selection of variables with several different methods (by name, position, or logical conditions...)

Comment: Thanks for all support, to me it looks a bit heavy to digest at the moment but started learning. However, trying to replicate the same in by creating a function and loop.                                                                                     
func <- function(data) {for (i in seq_along(data)) { if(data[i]=="Y") {data$newcol[i]=1} }
return(newcol)}
func(dataset_name)   .... would apricate if you help me know where have i gone wrong and how can i modify?

Comment: And how about doing the same but not necessarily by mentioning the column positions rather making the code smoother in a way such that it could go along the data frame column wise. Any tips please

Comment: My first line of code does that, it includes the entire dataframe. You can also do it with dplyr using `select(everything())` or just omitting select as in `starwars%>%mutate(new_col=map(., ~.=='brown')%>%reduce(., `|`)%>%replace(., .==FALSE, NA))`

Comment: you may consider accepting an answer if you feel it helped. Followup questions are better suited in a new question. We should avoid long theoretical discussions in the comments section